# I need select images based on color click

Tags: magento-1.9, products, color-swatches

I need an idea of how to do this. I'm using **Configurable Swatches** and placing in the images yours name colors.

**Example ::::**

- To white images, names: White
- To red images, names: Red

**Just here, all right. Now, my question ...**

> It is possible and how to do so, by clicking in the color image, just
>   stay in the gallery selected image colors?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You have to use magento attribute, or custom, Color

**2.** Add all the color label that you need

**3.** create configurable product

**4.** select attribite color or custom you create

**5.** go to the tab "associated products" and create individual variants with the "fast creation" setting by adding the color attribute of the individual product.

By doing so you will have the products that change photos based attribute color.